# How to specify which domain using ngrok

Tags: ngrok

I use mamp and I have virtual hosts all on port 8888. For example:

- site1.dev:8888
- site2.dev:8888

would point to `localhost/site1/`, `localhost/site2/` etc.

Before using virtual hosts, I would just change my docroot to whatever project I was currently working on and would start ngrok like so

`./ngrok http 8888` and it would launch and give me a random generated *.ngrok.io url.

My question is how do I specify the domain now since I am using virtual hosts?

I've tried `./ngrok http site1.dev:8888` and it starts but just serves up mamps webroot.

I am using a free account.

Answer (score 95, accepted):

If you prefer a free option, it is possible via:

```
ngrok http --host-header=site1.dev 80
```

Comment: The answer above is correct for the question asked. But if you are using something like Vagrant (e.g. Homestead) and you have a private IP assigned to the virtual machine, the above will not work. You will need to use `$ ngrok http -host-header=rewrite site1.dev:80`

Comment: I have .test domains with subdomains like 'subdomain.site.test:80'. Then, this way works for me: `$ ngrok http 80 --host-header=subdomain.site.test:80`

Comment: Little observation, as of today, the param is `--host-header=[your_domain]`. The answer is just missing the extra dash at the beginning.

Answer (score 6):

You can use custom domains with this syntax:

`ngrok http --hostname=dev.example.com 8000`

For reference: https://ngrok.com/docs#custom-domains

But a paid plan is needed.

Comment: This doesn't work UNLESS you create a corresponding CNAME..  wholly irritating.

Comment: Paid plan warning is important

Comment: @Pamput to confirm, the paid plan will work with custom alias on my localhost?

Comment: It's free now https://ngrok.com/blog-post/free-static-domains-ngrok-users

Answer (score 5):

### Works just for paid plan, otherwise not works :(

The correct way to use a custom subdomain name is follow:

```
ngrok http -subdomain=mycustomsubdomain 80
```

Will generate:

```
Forwarding                    http://mycustomsubdomain.ngrok.io -> 127.0.0.1:80
Forwarding                    https://mycustomsubdomain.ngrok.io -> 127.0.0.1:80
```

More in docs: https://ngrok.com/docs#http-subdomain

Comment: For paid plan users!